# "Find Unmatched" Query -- Using Queries instead of Tables

Tags: ms-access

I'm using Access 2010.

I have a database with multiple tables, each containing different components of teaching data.

Ultimately, I'd like to find "people who will be teaching a course in the upcoming semester and who have never taught before."

Currently, I am doing this through a series of steps:

1. Creating one table (through a query) that has a list of everyone who is teaching in the upcoming semester and what they are teaching (this data comes from multiple tables). **(tbl_NewInstructors)**
2. Creating another table (through a query) that has a list of everyone who has ever taught (but not including this upcoming semester). **(tbl_NewInstructors2)**
3. Running this select statement:

   ```
   SELECT tbl_NewInstructors.Name, tbl_NewInstructors.Course 

   FROM tbl_NewInstructors

   WHERE (((Exists (SELECT * from tbl_NewInstructors2 

   WHERE tbl_NewInstructors2.Name = tbl_NewInstructors.Name))=False));
   ```
4. Getting my list!

The main issue is that I have to create two tables each time I want to run this, and I would RATHER just run a query of my two current select queries, than a query on tables that I create through those queries. Unfortunately, when I try to run a query on the queries, it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you tried this, but in Access when you save a query, it acts like a table (really a "view") which you can then query using another query.  To keep it simple, just save each of the 2 queries you created in Step 1 and Step 2, and then run your query from Step 3, substituting the name of each of your saved queries for tbl_NewInstructors and tbl_NewInstructors2.  (And of course, you can save your query from Step 3, and just run that whenever you want this report).

Most likely, you could create a single SQL to do this, but I think saving the queries will be simpler, and will reuse what you already know how to do.

Comment: You know what, that worked. I had given up on it initially because it took FOREVER to load, so I kept just killing it; however, I tried it again before I stepped out to a meeting and I returned to my desk with the relevant info waiting for me. Thanks!